# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED as accessing to the vagrant guest by browser

Tags: laravel, apache, vagrant

I'm encountering a title's problem.

vagrantfile

```
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/var/www/app",
:owner => "vagrant",
:group => "vagrant",
:mount_options => ["dmode=777,fmode=775"]
```

httpd.conf

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/app/public"

<Directory "/var/www/app/public">
...
```

procedure

```
> sudo service httpd start
[  OK  ]

access https://192.168.33.10/ by host OS browser.

but ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED occured
```

/etc/httpd/log/error_log

```
no logs about this
```

/etc/httpd/log/access_log

```
no logs about this
```

netstat

```
> netstat -ant | grep 80
tcp        0      0 :::80                       :::*                        LISTEN
```

lsof

```
sudo lsof -i:80
COMMAND  PID    USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
httpd   3991    root    4u  IPv6  15275      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   3994 vagrant    4u  IPv6  15275      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   3995 vagrant    4u  IPv6  15275      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   3996 vagrant    4u  IPv6  15275      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   3997 vagrant    4u  IPv6  15275      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   3998 vagrant    4u  IPv6  15275      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   4105 vagrant    4u  IPv6  15275      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   4107 vagrant    4u  IPv6  15275      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   4108 vagrant    4u  IPv6  15275      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

service

```
> sudo service httpd status
httpd (pid  3991) is running...
```

I have no idea about this.

Could you help me??

Comment: It seems you are trying to access your site by `https` which uses port 443 by default.